# WebApi routing not passing value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a value to a controller / action in Web Api but it's not finding it.

My Route Mapping:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My ApiController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string MyThing()
    {
        return "thing";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string MyStuff(int myid)
    {
        return "something " + myid;
    }
```

My REST call via RestSharp:

```
var request = new RestRequest { Resource = "api/values/MyStuff/555", Method = Method.GET };
```

If I call `MyThing()` it works though. It seems that the problem is in passing the id value.

Comment: WEB API uses controller/http method/parameters
Method names should be Get/Post/Put/etc...

Comment: If you put an HttpGet or HttpPost attribute it will use the requested function.

Comment: Yes it will, but you should not. That goes against the web api routing purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the parameter name from "myid" to "id"

```
[HttpGet]
public string MyStuff(int **id**)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I found I had to add the parameter as an Query String, not a /path value.

```
api/values/MyStuff?myid=555
```

instead of

```
api/values/MyStuff/555
```

Comment: Kiran gave you a much better solution

Comment: I agree with Filip.  Kiran is a much better solution.  It's also more RESTful IMHO.

Comment: as much as it feels wrong to name passed values something as mundane as **id**, it's far better practice. yes more restful and elegant.